# Troubleshooting Docker Run and Attribute Error in casascan Execution

Tags: nix, casa

I'm currently working on a Flutter-based project that involves integrating Google Fit. As part of this process, Google requires a security assessment through CASA, specifically insisting on passing a tier 2 scanning procedure using the Fluid Attack scanning tool (https://appdefensealliance.dev/casa/tier-2/ast-guide/static-scan).

I encountered difficulties executing the command docker run casascan m gitlab:fluidattacks/universe@trunk /skims scan {App Repo Name}/config.yaml as it resulted in an error stating "mounting /proc: permission denied." To resolve this, I granted privileged attributes to the command, i.e., sudo docker run --privileged -it casascan m gitlab:fluidattacks/universe@trunk /skims scan nugenomics-mobile/config.yaml. However, While unpacking source archive from a gz file I am now facing a new error: "attribute 'attrPaths' missing."

Could someone please assist me with this issue?

I have tried downloading the repository manually to inspect. But couldn't figure out any issue..

Answer (score 0):

Open dockerfile, change the last line to version 23.04. Then rebuild, it solves my problem.

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM nixos/nix:latest
WORKDIR /usr/scan
COPY . /usr/scan/
RUN mkdir results
RUN nix-env -if https://github.com/fluidattacks/makes/archive/23.04.tar.gz
```